# How To Prevent jQuery Tabs From Changing Element Display Modes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have begun using jQuery tabs and it has an annoying side effect of changing the display mode of child elements in unpredictable and unwanted ways.

Some elements I have explicitly set to hidden: `$('#foo').hide()` appear anyway. Other elements that should just appear normally are hidden for no apparent reason.

Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Here is the DOM for the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Explanation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#igvTab">igv</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <ul>
            <li> blah blah
            <li> blah blah
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="igvTab">
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The the div with id=myDiv is the attachment point for an entire data visualization component whose DOM is entirely programmatically constructed. This component works just fine outside the jQUery tabbed context.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing a working example of what you're seeing. I'm assuming the tabs plugin is showing/hiding content that's overwriting the inline styles you're also trying to apply - perhaps you could instead use CSS classes with !important styles to override the tabs behaviour, but if you could post an example showing exactly what's happening we'd be able to give more help.

Comment: I added the html that hosts my component that is affected by the jQuery's approach to hiding/showing tabs.